# Match a string that begin with certain pattern and ends with a certain pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have to fetch all string that starts with `[[{` and ends with `}]]`. I tried to use:

```
'/^\[\[\{*$\}\}\]\]/'
```

but it does not work.

Basically I have to fetch some JSON string embedded inside HTML documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect use for [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and you can use them like so:

```
$re = '/(?=\[\[\{).*?(?<=\}\]\])/m'; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Here, [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) searches `$str` for all matches to the regular expression given in `$re` and puts them in `$matches`.

**[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dW4aI5)**

Comment: Please don't use backticks around things that aren't code.

Answer (score 2):

You should put anchors on it correctly. They are currently in the wrong place. This is the proper version. You should use it with `preg_match_all(...)`:

```
/\[\[\{.*?\}\]\]/
```

Comment: OK. Cleaning up my comments to keep the thread clean. +1 too!

Comment: Yes, `\[\[{.*?}]]` would do fine, but I think it's better to be explicit to avoid any confusion ^_^

Comment: I agree, I was just stating the obvious =)